# lapply over list of dataframes to subset and overwrite dfs

Tags: r

I am trying to subset each dataframe to exclude rows in which the first column is NA or "". I tried putting the dataframes into a list `df` and then using `lapply` over each dataframe. The code works, only that I am not sure how to overwrite each dataframe with the subset.

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1=c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA), v2=rep(1, 6))
df2 <- data.frame(v11=c(2, 3, 4, 5, NA, ""), v22=rep(1, 6))
df3 <- data.frame(v111=c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, NA), v222=rep(1, 6))

df <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)
df

$df1
# v1 v2
# 1  1  1
# 2  2  1
# 3  3  1
# 4 NA  1
# 5 NA  1
# 6 NA  1
# 
# $df2
# v11 v22
# 1    2   1
# 2    3   1
# 3    4   1
# 4    5   1
# 5 <NA>   1
# 6        1
# 
# $df3
# v111 v222
# 1    3    1
# 2    4    1
# 3    5    1
# 4    6    1
# 5    7    1
# 6   NA    1

lapply(names(df), function(x) df[[x]][!(is.na(df[[x]][,1]) | df[[x]][,1]==""), ])

# [[1]]
# v1 v2
# 1  1  1
# 2  2  1
# 3  3  1
# 
# [[2]]
# v11 v22
# 1   2   1
# 2   3   1
# 3   4   1
# 4   5   1
# 
# [[3]]
# v111 v222
# 1    3    1
# 2    4    1
# 3    5    1
# 4    6    1
# 5    7    1
```

In the end, I want `df3`, for example, to be as follows:

```
df3
#  v111 v222
#1    3    1
#2    4    1
#3    5    1
#4    6    1
#5    7    1
```

Comment: Good question.  I learned a few things from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify your `lapply` to the following form (in order to keep the names of the data frames too)

```
df <- lapply(df, function(x) x[!(is.na(x[1]) | x[1] == ""), ])
```

Then use `list2env` in order to get you data frames back into the global environment

```
list2env(df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Then you can inspect your new data frames by just

```
df1
##   v1 v2
## 1  1  1
## 2  2  1
## 3  3  1
```

etc.

Comment: yes! what an interesting little function, `list2env`. others might recommend @nrussell's answer to modify the dfs in the list, but I asked how to overwrite the original df objects, and this does it nicely.

Comment: I didn't know about that one either. (+1). Man, I'm learning so much today!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df <- lapply(
  names(df),
  function(x){
    df[[x]][!(is.na(df[[x]][,1]) | df[[x]][,1]==""), ]
  })
```

which gives you

```
> df
[[1]]
  v1 v2
1  1  1
2  2  1
3  3  1

[[2]]
  v11 v22
1   2   1
2   3   1
3   4   1
4   5   1

[[3]]
  v111 v222
1    3    1
2    4    1
3    5    1
4    6    1
5    7    1
```

Comment: It might be better than what I am looking for because it keeps the updated result in a list. But I'd like to overwrite the original dataframe objects.

Answer (score 0):

How about `complete.cases`:

```
df2[df2==""] <- NA
lapply(df, FUN = function(x) x[complete.cases(x),])

$df1
  v1 v2
1  1  1
2  2  1
3  3  1

$df2
  v11 v22
1   2   1
2   3   1
3   4   1
4   5   1

$df3
  v111 v222
1    3    1
2    4    1
3    5    1
4    6    1
5    7    1
```

If you really want to overwrite the prior objects.

```
dat_list <- lapply(dat, FUN = function(x) x[complete.cases(x),])
df1 <- dat_list$df1
df2 <- dat_list$df2
df3 <- dat_list$df3
```

Comment: @charles, that would work, but I'm looking to do it without naming each df like you do, e.g., not `df1 <- dat_list$df1`

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use `assign`

```
 names1 <- paste0("df", 1:3)
 for(i in seq_along(names1)){
 x <- get(names1[i])
 x1 <- x[!(is.na(x[,1])|x[1]==''),]
 assign(names1[i], x1)
 }

  df1
  # v1 v2
 #1  1  1
 #2  2  1
 #3  3  1

 df2
 #  v11 v22
 #1   2   1
 #2   3   1
 #3   4   1
 #4   5   1
```